# jquery link css class change

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, menuitem

I have the following main menu:

```
<div id="smoothmenu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/About">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="/Features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Support">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I would like to add a css class "selected" to a link when the link is clicked and remove the css class from all other links in the . This is to mark the page that the user has clicked to open.

Perhaps this can be done in a way where jquery reads the current path when the page loads and adds the css class to the corresponding menu link tag?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using AJAX to load the content? If not, this would be rather pointless.

Comment: No, it is an ASP.NET MVC view layout page. Like a Master page. And the main menu is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**CSS-Tricks Snippet**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)

Let's say you have navigation like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And you are at the URL:

**http://yoursite.com/about/team/**

And you want the About link to get a class of "active" so you can visually indicate it's the active navigation

```
$(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Essentially that will match links in the nav who's href attribute begins with "/about" (or whatever the secondary directory happens to be).

[**Further reading...**](http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-jquery-to-highlight-active-menu-item)

Comment: putting $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active'); in the $(document).ready(function () did the trick. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but try this out for size...

It compares the href attribute of each anchor element to the current window location for your navigation structure given above.

```
$('.ddsmoothmenu > ul#nav > li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $link = $this.children('a'),
        path = $link.attr('href');

    if (path == document.location.pathname) {
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Can be seen in action on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LdQft/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div#smoothmenu').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  $(this).addClass('Selected').siblings('a').removeClass('Selected');
});
```